# Please help me choose variables for a multiple linear regression analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, predictor

I'm shaky on statistics and I could really use some help.

I have a set of data at the zip code level. This data includes the distance from each zip code to the nearest pediatric surgeon. My goal is to determine what factors are associated with this distance. I have data at the zip code level on race (latino/hispanic, non-lat/hsp white, non-lat/hsp black etc), median income, percent uninsured children, rurality index.

My question is, if I were to run a multiple linear regression, which of these variables would I include? Off the top of my head, I expect people farther from surgeons to be poorer, more rural, less insured. But I have no idea how to tackle race. Also, do I run two different regressions, one for race, and one for these economic factors, or can I run one regression for all these variables?

Your help is much much appreciated.

My current Minitab output:

```
Term                                  Coef   SE Coef  T-Value  P-Value   VIF
Constant                             59.23      1.08    55.01    0.000
Unisured Perc                       0.1699    0.0265     6.42    0.000  1.08
MeanHouseIncome                    -0.000248  0.000010   -24.11    0.000  1.33
Percent; HISPANIC OR LATINO AND    -0.0128    0.0181    -0.71    0.479  1.19
Perc_NonHispLat - BlackAAalone     -0.4059    0.0175   -23.18    0.000  1.15
Perc_NonHispLat - Asian alone      -0.9212    0.0599   -15.39    0.000  1.31
Perc_NonHispLat - American Indi     0.4887    0.0352    13.87    0.000  1.04
PercRural                          0.39551   0.00731    54.13    0.000  1.52
```

New output after removing constant:
[image]

Comment: How many racial groups do you have? And do the shares add up to 1?  (eg. 15% black, 15% asian, 30% hispanic, 40% white?)

Comment: I have 5, White, Latino/Hispanic, Asian, Black/AA, American Indian. Yes, they add up to 100%. If I include white, the coefficient for Latino/Hispanic is positive, if I don't (as above), it is negative. It's confusing.

Comment: Do you know linear algebra? eg. matrix rank? (I'm figuring out how much math to use))

Comment: No, unfortunately. :(

Comment: I would re-scale income to be in thousands of dollars so your coefficients are similar in size to the others (it will not alter the model fit, of course). See @MatthewGunn answer for your most pressing question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y_i$ be our outcome variable, distance to a surgeon.

For simplicity, let's imagine there are only three races: white, black, and asian.

Let $s^w_i$ be the share of region $i$ that is white, $s^b_i$ be the share of region $i$ that is black, and $s^a_i$ be the share of region $i$ that is asian. Let's imagine our data is pretty sensible so that for each region, all the shares add up (note they may not add up precisely because of rounding):

$$s^w_i + s^b_i + s^a_i \approx 1$$

Let's say we want to estimate four variables $\beta_0$, $\beta_w$, $\beta_b$, and $\beta_a$ in the following the linear model:

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_w s^w_i + \beta_b s^b_i + \beta_a s^a_i + \epsilon_i $$

**We actually can't do that!**

What's wrong? Intuitively, the problem is that we only have THREE unknown variables, not FOUR. Since the shares sum to 1 for every region, the sum of the effects for each race $\beta_w + \beta_b + \beta_a$ is the *SAME THING* as the constant, baseline effect $\beta_0$.

Your stats package may not even let you run that regression. And if it does let you run the regression, it will either toss out one of the races (i.e. give you solution (2) below) or give you entirely bizarre results.

#### Solution 1: Remove the constant

You could estimate the regression model:

$$ y_i = \beta_w s^w_i + \beta_b s^b_i + \beta_a s^a_i + \epsilon_i $$

In this case $\beta_w$ would be the expected distance to a surgeon if a region was all white. $\beta_b$ would be the expected distance to a surgeon if a region was all black, etc...

#### Solution 2: Exclude 1 race and estimate effects *relative* to that race.

This is probably a better idea. Run the regression:

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_{1} s^b_i + \beta_{2} s^a_i + \epsilon_i $$

In this case, $\beta_0$ would be mean distance to a surgeon if a region was neither black nor asian (i.e. all white). $\beta_{1}$ would be the *additional* distance to a surgeon if a region was all black compared to the case if the region was all white.

#### How are solution 1 and solution 2 linked?

The math of linear regression is that both approach (1) and approach (2) are equivalent in the sense that if you ran both regressions (and $s_i^w + s^b_i + s^a_i = 1$ holds precisely in the data for each region $i$), you would find:

$$\beta_w = \beta_0 \quad \quad \beta_b = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \quad \quad \beta_a = \beta_0 + \beta_2$$

#### Summary:

You want to include all your economic variables and either (1) include all your racial groups and don't include a constant or (2) exclude 1 racial group and run a standard regression.

(2) is probably the more robust approach.

Comment: Question, when you are referring to β0, what does it represent? I don't think at the moment I am using all races added together as a separate variable. Is that was β0 refers to?

Comment: @PediatricsCore In your example above, the estimate of $\beta_0$ is 59.23. It is the constant.

Comment: @PediatricsCore Another way to think about $\beta_0$ is that it's a coefficient on a variable that is *always equal to* 1. Regression $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i,1} + \epsilon_i$ is equivalent to a regression $y_i = \beta_0 x_{i,0} + \beta_1 x_{i,1} + \epsilon_i$ where $x_{i,0}=1$ for all $i$. That's why if you include the shares for each race, AND try to estimate a constant effect $\beta_0$, you have a problem because your data isn't [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) because  $x_{i,0} = 1 = s^b_i + s_i^a + s^w_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Okay, so I ran the regression without the constant. I have added it to my post above.

Comment: This is method 1. How is method 2 better, and can you explain how exactly I would run method 2. Do I need to transform the data at all? And, again, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @PediatricsCore I think I don't understand exactly what your variables are. What *exactly* is "Perc_NonHispLat - Asian alone"?

Comment: Perc_NonHispLat-Asian alone means Asians that could not be classified as Hispanic or Latinos. It's the percent of Asians in the whole population.

Comment: @PediatricsCore To do method 2, include a constant but simply leave one single racial group out. The effects will be relative to the group left out.

Comment: I'll try that. To be clear, how do I interpret the results from method 1: for example, above, does it mean that Latino/Hispanic population percent increases 0.5884 percent for every mile from a surgeon, if all other variables are ignored? Seems kind if high, meaning every 10 miles, Latino Hispanic population increases 5.8 percent?

Comment: I did a correlation (Pearson) between each variable and distance. It's shows different relationships than what the regression suggests. It tells two different stories. Why is this? Distance v Unis18Perc = 0.093

Distance v MeanHouseInc = -0.255

Distance v Percent; HISPANIC OR LATINO AND = -0.112

Distance v and Perc_NonHispLat - White alone = 0.212

Distance v Perc_NonHispLat - BlackAAalone = -0.178

Distance v and Perc_NonHispLat - Asian alone = -0.274

Distance v and Perc_NonHispLat - American Indi = 0.127

Distance v and PercRural = 0.441

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use all the explanatory variables you want within one single multiple regression model.  You can enter a race variable simply as a binomial variable (0, 1) whether a given race is prevalent in a given zip code.  I think you could even include them as a % mix.  Let's say in a zip code you have 60% white, 25% hispanic, and 15% black... you could probably enter those variables as such.  I don't see why this would mispecify your model.  When you include all those variables, your model may have several of them that are not statistically significant enough.  You may consider removing those from the model and see how the model with fewer variables perform vs. the model with more variable.  Simpler models that perform as well or close to more complicated models are deemed superior (principle of parsimony).  They typically generalize better (meaning they perform better in Hold Out sample or test sample if you will).

Comment: Thank you. I've been using percents as you suggested. I've run all the variables together in Minitab and get the following:

Comment: I've added the results to my question up top

Comment: As a followup, if you see the results above, the coefficient for Hispanic or Latino is negative. If I added "Whites" as a variable, the Hispanic Latino coefficient becomes positive. This tells two different stories.

Comment: @PediatricsCore The coefficient on Hispanic Latino actually has two *extremely different* interpretations depending on whether the white share is included in the regression or if it isn't. See my answer for an explanation.